# How to get non-heap "code cache" details using jstat

Tags: java, windows, java-8, jstat, jvm-codecache

I want to find the *non-heap memory* **code cache** details of a remote JVM (JDK 8) running on windows from my windows machine. I can get the details using **jconsole**. But, what i need is to get the values using **jstat** command. GUI monitoring tools doesn't serves my purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use jstat arg and pid of java process e.g. for pid 616

jstat -compiler 616

Compiled Failed Invalid   Time   FailedType FailedMethod

```
7979      5       0   121.28          1 weblogic/xml/babel/baseparser/BaseParser parseSome
```

jstat -printcompilation 616

Compiled  Size  Type Method

```
7979    331    1 weblogic/servlet/internal/CompleteMessageTimeoutTrigger timerExpired
```

jconsole Memory tab and select Code Cache in drop down shows the current Code Cache Size

To get your JVM defaults (find on windows or grep on unix):

java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "CodeCache"

```
uintx CodeCacheExpansionSize                    = 65536                               {pd product}
uintx CodeCacheMinimumFreeSpace                 = 512000                              {product}
uintx InitialCodeCacheSize                      = 2555904                             {pd product}
 bool PrintCodeCache                            = false                               {product}
 bool PrintCodeCacheOnCompilation               = false                               {product}
uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                     = 251658240                           {pd product}
 bool UseCodeCacheFlushing                      = true                                {product}
```

Answer (score 1):

code cache get filled up with interpreter, compiled, runtime stub codes.

the key user of codecache is compiled code.
you can get compiled code stats using jstat. this will give decent info on code cache use.

Comment: Can you updated to mention how to get these stats please?